# NumPy multi-dimensional array indexing

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing

Assume the following example:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 10, 200))
>>> print(a.shape)
(3, 10, 200)
>>> 
>>> idx = np.random.randint(0, 3, 10)
>>> print(idx)
[2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0]
```

`a`is an array of shape `(K=3, J=10, I=200)`.

`idx` is an array of the same length as `a.shape[1]`, i.e. contains J = 10 elements. Each index denotes which element of K should be chosen.

Now I'd like to select from the first axis (K) by the indices `idx` to get an array of shape `(J=10, I=200)` back.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using `idx` to index along the first axis, while selecting per element along the second axis and all along the last one. Thus, we can use [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), like so -

```
a[idx, np.arange(len(idx)),:]
```

Skipping the trailing `:` gives us a shorter version -

```
a[idx, np.arange(len(idx))]
```